# Busqueda automática Ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Haciendo un livesearch con ajax y php tengo este error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\book\server.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\book\server.php on line 18
```

Realmente no sé como solucionarlo

```
index

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>AJAX - XML</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<body>

Buscar persona: <input type = "type" id="nombre" onkeyup = "mostrarUsuario(this.value)" placeholder = "Ingresar nombre"/>

<div id="info"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var resultado = document.getElementById("info");

    function mostrarUsuario(nombre)
    {

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (nombre.length === ""){
            resultado.innerHTML = "";
        }else{
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    resultado.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","server.php?nombre=" + nombre,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

servidor.php
<?php

require "connect.php";

$nombre= $_GET['nombre'];

if (!empty($nombre))
{
    $persona= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nombre);


    $sql=("SELECT * FROM tbl_employees WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$persona."%'");


    $resultadoBD=$con->query($sql);


    while($fila = $resultadoBD->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $fila['nombre']. " ";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

}




?>
```

Ya probe mirando el query pero no sé cual pueda ser el error

Comment: Lo tienes en un repositorio? porque a lo visto lo veo bien.

Comment: mira https://github.com/Dan0221/4.dic.17

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo `connect.php` no estas seleccionando la base de datos, por lo que al ejecutar la consulta da error y te devuelve un boleano (FALSE), al ser `$resultadoBD` false en lugar de un objeto y utilizar `fetch_assoc` sobre él obtienes el error que indicas.

Simplemente corrige la conexion en `connect.php` de esta forma:

```
mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

Es decir, añade la base de datos a utilizar como 4° parámetro en [connect.php](https://github.com/Dan0221/4.dic.17/blob/master/connect.php)

También sería buena idea añadir una comprobación cuando ejecutes la query

```
if ( $resultadoBD=$con->query($sql) ) {
    // se ejecuto correctamente
} else { 
    // falló 
    printf("Error: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```